# Find $a$ in terms of $n$ so that there would be one intersection between the lines $y=\log_{n} x$ and $y=x+a$?

Tags: logarithms, systems-of-equations

During math class we were introduced to solving systems of equations in the Algebra II curriculum (not I). After looking at intersecting lines, I formulated a problem I found interesting:

> Find $a$ in terms of $n$ so that there would be **one** intersection between the 
>   lines $y=\log_{n} x$ and $y=x+a$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Considering the shapes of the graphs, there will be one intersection provided the line is tangent to the curve.

The curve is $$y=\log_nx=\frac{\ln x}{\ln n}\implies \frac{dy}{dx}=\frac{1}{x\ln n}$$

The gradient of the line is $1$ so $$\frac{1}{x\ln n}=1\implies x=\frac{1}{\ln n}\implies y=-\frac{\ln(\ln n)}{\ln n}$$

So the equation of the tangent is $$y+\frac{\ln(\ln n)}{\ln n}=x-\frac{1}{\ln n}$$

Therefore $$a=-\frac{\ln(\ln n)}{\ln n}-\frac{1}{\ln n}$$